# UseState array Hooks return a new object in every change in the input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm using React hooks for a project I'm working on. I'm coming across a situation where I want to use an array in the useState hook, but I'm not really certain on how to do this.

I created a table which changes the number of its columns dynamically, according to the number of days of the month.

I've tried something like this:

```
const [inText, setInText] = useState([]);
const inputText = (e) => {
    setInText([...inText,{
        id:inText.length,
        value:e.target.value
    }]);
}
```

numberOfDays is a variable which I calculate. It contains the number of days in the current month.

```
const renderINP = () => {
    let td = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
        td.push(<td key={i}><input type="text" onChange={inputText} /></td>);
    }
    return td;
};
```

This is the code which renders the table to the browser:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr className="work-days">
            <td>Working days</td>
            {renderINP()}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to catch the 'inText' with cosole.log(inText). When I type something in the input, like 0 for example, it creates an object, {id: 0, value: '0'}. When I type again, it creates two objects
{id: 0, value: '0'} and {id: 1, value: '0.'}. Also, when I delete something, it creates another object.

How can I create just one object for every input, and how can I get the value of every inText individually? For example, get the value of inText in the second input, not the value off all objects.

Comment: what is `numberOfItems` ? where do you set it? Is it a state variable ?

Comment: It is not too clear to me what your intention is but it sounds like you need to use useReducer instead of useState.

Comment: you mean numberOfDays i think ,it's a variable who contain the number of days of the current month, i get it from a function return number of days of the current month @AntonioPantano

Comment: @code90 for exemple if i want type 0.5 in the first input it will create thre object in the array who will have three different id and values , the values will be '0' and '.' and '5' ,how can this be avoided and create just one object in the array with the value of '0.5'

Comment: Ah ok, then try with `onBlur` instead of `onChange`. You will need to click outside of the input box to get the update kick in. But still, this won't fully address your issue. I suggest using useReducer. just a draft code sample: `onChange={(value) => dispatch({index: i, value})}`

Comment: @code90 i tried onBlur and it's really sloved a part of the problem , but when i type in the first input for exemple '0.5' and click outside the input it creates one object with value of 0.5 and id 0 , if i want to change the value again in the first input it creates another obeject ,the first one {id: 0, value: '1'} and the other {id: 1, value: '0.5'}

Comment: Right, that's why I said it won't address your issue. You need a better solution there. useReducer should be the way to go with. I can provide a solution later in the day maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState is mostly used for keeping single values. In this case, you have an array of objects and want to update value for individual objects. useReducer is preferable.

You can read more about [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

This should do what you are looking for:

```js
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "ADD") {
      const newState = [...state];
      newState.push({ id: action.id, value: action.value });
      return newState;
    }

    if (action.type === "UPDATE") {
      const newState = [...state];
      const foundItem = newState.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
      foundItem.value = action.value;
      return newState;
    }
  };

  const initialState = [];

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const numberOfDays = 7;

  const inputText = ({ id, value }) => {
    if (state.find((item) => item.id === id)) {
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE", id, value });
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: "ADD", id, value });
    }

    console.log(state);
  };

  const renderINP = () => {
    let td = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
      td.push(
        <td key={i}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => inputText({ id: i, value: e.target.value })}
          />
        </td>
      );
    }
    return td;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr className="work-days">
            <td>Working days</td>
            {renderINP()}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      {JSON.stringify(state)}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69816586/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).